# SQL Server table-valued function problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just got another query that I'm pulling what remaining hair I have left out over here.

I have 4 tables (`Product`, `Customers`, `Orders` and `Order Details`) I need to create a valued table function that passes Country Name to the function. I also need the function to join my `Customers` table with my `Orders` table. I ideally want to filter Countries by Order Date. So I'd like to able to Select from the function that tells me orders from a certain country within a certain date range.

So far I've tried the following with not much success:

```
USE sample;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION Orders_By_Country (@Country VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN (SELECT Customers.Country, Customers.CompanyName
                    FROM Customers
                   WHERE Customers.Country = Orders.ShipCountry
                 AND Country = @Country);
```

I don't have a `Country` column in my `Orders` table so maybe that is why it's not working. Not sure how to join these two. `Orders` and `Customers` share `CustomerID` as a relation but trying that gave me an error as well.

Any ideas? I have to go to bed now, but I'll check back first thing in the morning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `Orders` table to make decisions or if you want to return one or multiple columns from that table in your TVF, you need to **join** to it!

```
CREATE FUNCTION Orders_By_Country (@Country VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN 
       (SELECT Customers.Country, Customers.CompanyName
        FROM Customers
        INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId
        WHERE 
            Customers.Country = Orders.ShipCountry
            AND Country = @Country);
```

or then you might not need it at all - seeing that you have a `Country` column on the `Customers` table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Orders_By_Country (@Country VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN 
       (SELECT Customers.Country, Customers.CompanyName
        FROM Customers
        WHERE 
            Customers.Country = @Country);
```

Comment: Thank You very much Marc. Just what I was looking for!